# MVC 3, Razor View- override default form post

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, dom-events

I am stuck at a small problem. I have this button within a form which already posts to a controller action method for example  `Edit()`.    Now I want have a cancel button which will post to a different action method for example `Edit(int id)`.  I am trying to override the default post as specified in the `Html.Begin` form so I attached a Javascript event but the event does not event hit.  I know if I use a action link it works like a charm but then I have worry about making the link look like a button. Also I cannot place the link into a different form for the sake of physical placement with different elements in the form. Would truly appreciate any  tips.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "RunLogEntry", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) { 

        <input id="create" class="art-button" type="submit" value="Save" /> 
        <input id="cancel" class="art-button" type="submit" value="Cancel" />       
        }


    $("#cancel").click(function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault(); //Keep form from posting 
    window.location.href = "REDIRECT URL";

    });
```

Comment: Please use Firebug or other console to check for errors. Did you enclose javascript code in `<script type='text/javascript'></script>`>? Your code looks fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the type of your `cancel` button to `button`. This way, it won't trigger the form submit by default. You'll need to handle it with JavaScript.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "RunLogEntry", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })) { 
    <input id="create" class="art-button" type="submit" value="Save" /> 
    <input id="cancel" class="art-button" type="button" value="Cancel" />       
}
```

Also, in this case, you won't need `e.preventDefault();` line.

```
$("#cancel").click(function(e) { 
    window.location.href = "REDIRECT URL";
});
```